# Does Router.refresh() not work in NextJs 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the following structure in my app:

```
.
└── /course/  
    ├── page.tsx
    └── create-section-button.tsx
```

Where page-> server component. Data is fetched from prisma in it. It displays a list of sections in a course. It also houses an instance of create-section-button, which is a client component.
Here's the onClick handler:

```
"use client"

import { createCourseSection } from "@/actions";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

async function handleClick() {
      setLoading(true);
      await createCourseSection({
        courseSlug,
        sectionName: `Section ${secNum}`,
        index: secNum,
      });
      setLoading(false);
      router.refresh();
    }
```

createCourseSection is a server action which has just a prisma.section.create({})

In nextjs-13, it used to work all fine. I had to upgrade to Nextjs-14 cos I needed to use the unstable_noStore() function for some other module of the app, so this doesn't work anymore.

**Edit**
I've added import statements to clarify imports.
Clarified folder structure

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Please edit the above & add the full code, including import statements of create-section-button.tsx component.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> *router.refresh() not working ...*

**Possible Cause :**

- `useRouter()` hook imported from `'next/router'` which is for pages router,
- While `'next/navigation'` is for app router in client side components
  for changing routes.

**Solution :**

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
```

*Beacuse `create-section-button.tsx` is an Client component, as it uses click event.*

**Please Read :**

- **useRouter() (App router):** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router
- **useRouter() (Pages router):** https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router

> ***If you have any doubts, leave a comment.***

Comment: Hey! I've imported from next/navigation itself. From the network tab I see that after the action, there's a network request to receive the new RSC payload, but its not getting reconciled.. In the same application on the same page, a similar functionality with router.refresh works flawlessly